# React.js without JSX - "Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use React.js component without JSX and receive such warning:

`Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead. See: http://fb.me/react-legacyfactory`

I've visited link but suggested `createFactory` solution didn't help me :/

**app.js**

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var TagsInput = React.createFactory(require('./tagsinput')); // no luck

var TagsComponent = React.createClass({
  displayName: "TagsComponent",
  saveTags: function () {
    console.log('tags: ', this.refs.tags.getTags().join(', '));
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      React.createElement("div", null,
        React.createElement(TagsInput, {ref: "tags", tags: ["tag1", "tag2"]}),
        React.createElement("button", {onClick: this.saveTags}, "Save")
      )
    );
  }
});

React.render(React.createElement(TagsComponent, null), document.getElementById('tags'));
```

**tagsinput.js**

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/olahol/react-tagsinput/master/react-tagsinput.js

I cannot figure out what is the problem here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`React.createClass(spec)` returns a **component**.

`React.createElement(component, props, ...children)` creates an **element**.

`React.createFactory(component)` returns a **factory** function, which can be used to create an **element**.

`React.createFactory(a)(b, c, d)` is the same as `React.createElement(a, b, c, d)`.

You get the warning when you call a **component** directly, like `component()`.  If you want to call it like a function, use createFactory

```
var factory = React.createFactory(component);
var element = factory(props, ...children);
```

Or use createElement:

```
var element = React.createElement(component, props, ...children);
```

In 0.13 this will give an error instead of a warning:

```
var element = component(props, ...children);
```

Also because React.DOM is going away, you should create dom **elements** the same way you create **component** based **elements**

<sup>Edit: looks like React.DOM is sticking around for now.</sup>

```
var div = React.createFactory('div');
var element = div(props, ...children);

// or

var element = React.createElement('div', props, ...children);
```

<sub>Bold used to show consistent terms.  `...children` means any number of child arguments</sub>

Comment: What about `component.type(component.props)` returns an element? Is there an approved way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap all of your child components in `createFactory` as well, I was able to get your code to run without that specific warning by wrapping `Tag` and `Input` in `createFactory`.

[**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/pozeku/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: I used to fix this with wrapping `Tag` and `Input` into `React.createElement`.

Answer (score -1):

For me. The culprit is recompose. I want to convert my functional component to pure. Then I solved it by using memo.

Using memo from react:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const Component = (props) {
return (
// Component code
)
}

// Wrap component using "memo" HOC
export default memo(Component);
Using pure from recompose:

import React from 'react';
import { pure } from 'recompose';

const Component = (props) {
return (
// Component code
)
}

// Wrap component using "pure" HOC
export default pure(Component);
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure if your answer address the problem.